# Using Shiro's PasswordMatcher with a custom realm

Tags: java, authentication, shiro

I'm using Apache Shiro with a custom JDBC realm to retrieve a user’s salt, password, hash algorithm name and number of hash iterations from the database which are all stored as separate columns.

The problem is I'm unsure how I should handle the salt that has been retrieved from the database when using the PasswordMatcher to verify the user's password matches that stored in the database.

When using the HashedCredentialsMatcher the salt is set using the `setCredentialsSalt` method, however it seems that this isn't the case when using the PasswordMatcher instead of the HashedCredentialsMatcher.

The code I'm using in the custom JDBC realm is as follows

```
@Override 
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException { 

        //code to retrieve user details from database removed for brevity 

        SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, passwdSalt.password, getName()); 
        info.setCredentialsSalt(new SimpleByteSource(passwdSalt.salt)); 

        DefaultPasswordService passwordService = new DefaultPasswordService(); 
        DefaultHashService hashService = new DefaultHashService(); 
        PasswordMatcher passwordMatcher = new PasswordMatcher(); 

        hashService.setHashAlgorithmName(passwdSalt.hashAlgorithmName); 
        hashService.setHashIterations(passwdSalt.hashIterations); 
        passwordService.setHashService(hashService); 
        passwordMatcher.setPasswordService(passwordService); 
        setCredentialsMatcher(passwordMatcher); 

        return info; 
}
```

Having stepped through the code I've confirmed that the problem is definitely due to the salt not being used when hashing the password entered by the user in order to match it against the hashed password in the database. In DefaultPasswordService.java when the method passwordsMatch(Object submittedPlaintext, String saved) is called on line 160 the object named `request` contains the following

```
algorithmName=null 
iterations=0 
salt=null 
source=cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

The next line of code on line 161 calls `computeHash(request)`

In DefaultHashService.java when the method `computeHash(HashRequest request)` is called, on lines 155 and 157 the variables algorithmName and iterations are correctly set to `SHA-256` and `1` respectively. On line 159 the method `getPublicSalt(request)` is called however it retuns null.

Has anyone else used Shiro's PasswordMatcher with a custom realm and if how do you tell Shiro to use the salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a message on the Shiro mailing list and got a reply saying that the PasswordMatcher by default does not look at anything in the AuthenticationInfo other than authenticationInfo.getCredentials().

For further details, the archived message on the mailing list is available at http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Migrating-from-HashedCredentialMatcher-to-PasswordMatcher-td7577808.html

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to hunt down this url in one of my projects - http://meri-stuff.blogspot.com/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html

The article links to this file [JNDIAndSaltAwareJdbcRealm](https://github.com/SomMeri/SimpleShiroSecuredApplication/blob/authentication_stored_in_database/src/main/java/org/meri/simpleshirosecuredapplication/realm/JNDIAndSaltAwareJdbcRealm.java)

I've used that class successfully in my project to use salt in the password hash.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Meri's excellent page on using Shiro was the original basis for the custom realm I'm using and it works fine when using the HashedCredentialsMatcher but if I swap it for the PasswordMatcher the salt seems to get lost.

Comment: @PaulH - Sorry, I should have read the question carefully. Taking a look to see what I've done in my project. We had to use a stored procedure in our setup to generate the password hash with a given salt.

Comment: No worries, how are you handling the salt when retrieving the record from the database in order to compare the hashed password with the password entered by the user? Also are you using the HashedCredentialsMatcher or the PasswordMatcher in your code?

Comment: It seems 2am is a bad time to try and understand code you've written badly 6 months ago. I've put the file in a [pastie](http://pastebin.com/ciWbfr7p) . I'll log in again in a few hours (after some sleep) and see if I can make sense of it, if you haven't been able to.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the credentials created by the [Shiro Command Line Hasher](https://shiro.apache.org/command-line-hasher.html) in [Shiro1CryptFormat](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.5/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/crypto/hash/format/Shiro1CryptFormat.html), then you can use the `DefaultPasswordService` in your realm:

```
        final PasswordMatcher passwordMatcher = new PasswordMatcher();
        passwordMatcher.setPasswordService(new DefaultPasswordService());
        realm.setCredentialsMatcher(passwordMatcher);
```