# Using JDBCRealm to authenticate user with Shiro

Tags: shiro, jdbcrealm

I am trying to authenticate a servlet running within Tomcat 6 using Shiro.

I have the following shiro.ini file:

```
[main]
ps = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
pm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
pm.passwordService = $ps

aa = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.AllowAllCredentialsMatcher
sm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.SimpleCredentialsMatcher

jof = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
jof.resourceName = jdbc/UserDB
jof.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
jof.resourceRef = true

realm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
realm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
realm.credentialsMatcher = $pm
; Note factories are automatically invoked via getInstance(),
;   see org.apache.shiro.authc.config.ReflectionBuilder::resolveReference
realm.dataSource = $jof

securityManager.realms = $realm

[urls]
/rest/** = authcBasic
/prot/** = authcBasic
```

And the following in my database:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----------+------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| username | email            | verified | password                                     | password_salt            |
+----------+------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| admin    | a.muys@********* |        1 | ojSiTecNwRF0MunGRvz3DRSgP7sMF9EAR77Ol/2IAY8= | eHp9XedrIUa5sECfOb+KOA== |
+----------+------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I use the `SimpleCredentialsManager` it authenticates fine against a plaintext password in the users table. Trying to use the `PasswordMatcher` has been extremely frustrating.

The password and password_salt were obtained via the shiro-tools `Hasher` utility.

When I try to authenticate against a basic `HelloWorld` servlet I use for testing (path=rest/hello, context=/ws), I get the following in the logs:

```
15:35:38.667 [http-8080-2] TRACE org.apache.shiro.util.ClassUtils - Unable to load clazz named [ojSiTecNwRF0MunGRvz3DRSgP7sMF9EAR77Ol/2IAY8=] from class loader [WebappClassLoader
  context: /ws
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@79ddd026
]
```

(Full log at https://gist.github.com/recurse/5915693 )

It appears to be trying to load my hashed password as a classname. Is this a bug, or a configuration error on my part? If it is a bug, how can I work around it? If it is a configuration error, what am I missing?

Comment: just what i was looking for, thank you, btw did you follow any tutorial for this kind of set up ? i was trying to integrate my jdbc realm with sha hashes and couldnt find any relevant tutorials.

Comment: No. I read the documentation on the Shiro site to understand the basic structure of the API; then, I checked out the code and reverse engineered the JDBC configuration.

Comment: where in `shiro.ini` does it specify that you use the `users` table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, thanks for providing a lot of information for this question - it makes providing an answer a lot easier.

By looking at your sample database row list, it does not appear that you are storing the output that the PasswordService expects when performing a hashed password comparison.  For example:

```
$ java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/shiro/tools/shiro-tools-hasher/1.2.2/shiro-tools-hasher-1.2.2-cli.jar -p
Password to hash:
Password to hash (confirm):
$shiro1$SHA-256$500000$uxaA2ngfdxdXpvSWzpuFdg==$hOJZc+3+bFYYRgVn5wkbQL+m/FseeqDtoM5mOiwAR3E=
```

The String that starts with `$shiro1$` is what you would save to the `password` column in the database.  There is no need for a separate salt column as all the information Shiro needs is in the `$shiro1$...` String.

The `DefaultPasswordService` uses the same default configuration parameters (SHA-256, 500,000 iterations, etc) so if you use the Hasher CLI tool as I've shown above (no extra hash algorithm config), you don't need to customize the `DefaultPasswordService` POJO any further.  However, if you change the hashing parameters on the CLI, you need to ensure that the same parameters are configured on the `DefaultPasswordService` bean (and/or its internal HashingService).

If you are still in testing and can change your DB schema, I'd recommend doing that now to have a single password field that stores the `$shiro1$...` string.  Then you use the PasswordService as documented here under **Usage**:

http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/credential/PasswordService.html

Comment: Configuring this in `shiro.ini` is described on the **Usage** page linked by @LesHazlewood. For configuration done in Java see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45225711/2969332