# Apache Shiro - password format issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hash, shiro

I try to use PasswordMatcher with DefaultPasswordService with DefaultHashService.

```
DefaultHashService hashService = new DefaultHashService();
hashService.setHashIterations(10000); 
hashService.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha512Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
hashService.setGeneratePublicSalt(true);

DefaultPasswordService passwordService = new DefaultPasswordService();
passwordService.setHashService(hashService);
String encryptedPassword = passwordService.encryptPassword("password");
System.out.println("Result:"+encryptedPassword);
```

And here is the result which I must save to database in the column PASSWORD.

> $shiro1$SHA-512$10000$T5nkQEA3qjMLPuB/x+WN4Q==$qWViYjBljsMwH7FSvhecKlxQqXY11lv8eS4guxD9t8D4HTeKclN/muyTnhzYZ+YvI1YkEg6L7T2kM3qykUG0XQ==

Everything is working. However my question is why are iterations number and algorithm name saved together with salt and password? This case we do inform the potential attacker, who dumps our database about such important properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, we aim to protect user passwords even when an attacker knows all implementation secrets.  This is known as "[white-box encryption](http://www.whiteboxcrypto.com/files/2012_misc.pdf)":

> In such a context, a ‘white-box attacker’ has full access to the software implementation of a cryptographic algorithm: the binary is completely visible and alterable by the attacker; and the attacker has full control over the execution platform (CPU calls, memory registers, etc.). Hence, the implementation itself is the sole line of defence.

That being said, you can store the hash algorithm and iteration count together with the password, as you have to assume the attacker also has access to the code/binaries anyways (which is not unlikely if they have access to the database).

Storing the number of iterations together with the hash has an additional benefit:  In the future you might want to change to a larger number of iterations, since processing power has increased.  You can then easily upgrade your database by going through all the hashes with the old number of iterations, apply a number of additional iterations and store the new result in the database, upgraded to a more secure scheme.

Similarly, if you add the hash algorithm to the hash, you may easily change to other password schemes (bcrypt, ...) later and upgrade users gracefully on their next login.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why do we set in shiro the following settings if they are taken from the pass, I mean: hashService.hashIterations = 10000,hashService.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-512, hashService.generatePublicSalt = true. Is it unnecessary?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Shiro API, but in either case you have to set them upon first creation of a hash for a user, and I don't know if Shiro can derive them from the generated hash itself or if you have to provide these values.

Comment: Actually those settings should not be in the code. DefaultPasswordService actually doesn't even use them, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902798/2969332

Comment: Thanks for reference. The mailing list thread mentioned there reads: "This is because it is expected that, when using the PasswordService, the credentials object is a Modular Crypt Format [1] String that has the salt (and any other necessary data) embedded in the String. Because of this assumption (...), the implementation does not check for any properties other than just authcInfo.getCredentials();"
So Shiro does in fact retrieve the iterations from the password string when decrypting and only respects the iteration settings when encrypting.

Answer (score 1):

It is so when you change the default algorithm of your password service, you can still check against hashes of previously generated passwords.

As for your concern about aiding the potential hacker, there is a simple way to circumvent this, add a private salt string to the hashing algorithm:

```
private static final String PRIVATE_SALT = "some_random_string_you_only_know";
...
hashService.setPrivateSalt(new SimpleByteSource(PRIVATE_SALT));
```